# django model instance edit

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 3 models set as follows:

```
#models.py
class Room(models.Model):
    room_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True, null=False, blank=False)
    isolation_status = models.BooleanField()


class Treatment(models.Model):
    room_number = models.ForeignKey(Room, primary_key=True)
    treated = models.BooleanField()

class Isolation(models.Model):
    room_number = models.ForeignKey(Room, primary_key=True)
```

What I need to do when I create a new Treatment object is set the Room.isolation_status field to False.

```
#views.py
class AddTxView(FormView):
    template_name = 'addtx.html'
    form_class = TxForm
    success_url = '/rooms/addtx/'

def update_iso(self, form):
    instance = Room.objects.get(room_number=room_number)
    instance.isolation_status = False

def form_valid(self, form):
    save_it = form.save(commit=False)
    save_it.save()
    return super(AddTxView, self).form_valid(form)

#forms.py
class TxForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Treatment
```

When should I call the update_iso function? After the save()? Should I be using a class-based view for

Comment: You *are* using a class-based view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set this in the model. Whenever you save a Treatment, check if it is new. If it is, set the isolation_status of the room_number to false.

```
#models.py
class Room(models.Model):
    room_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True, null=False, blank=False)
    isolation_status = models.BooleanField()


class Treatment(models.Model):
    room_number = models.ForeignKey(Room, primary_key=True)
    treated = models.BooleanField() 

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        is_new = False
        if self.pk is None:
            is_new = True
        super(Treatment,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if is_new:
            self.room_number.isolation_status = False
            self.room_number.save()

class Isolation(models.Model):
    room_number = models.ForeignKey(Room, primary_key=True)
```

by doing this it will work whenever you add the Treatment (be it in your views or in the admin).

Answer (score 1):

Before saving the Treatment object you can do it like:

```
form_obj = form.save(commit=False)
form_obj.room_number.isolation_status = False
form_obj.save()
```

Comment: Indeed, that's the only real reason to override `form_valid` and call save with commit=False. I can't imagine why the OP was doing it already.